# Migration to react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've had a problem with migration between `react-router-dom` v5 to v6. After update my package I do a few upgrades in the code. Below is my version of code in v5 and with v6 and also `Routing` component which give me a problem.

v5

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <AppContextProvider>
          <Routing />
        </AppContextProvider>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

v6

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppContextProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Routing />
        </Routes>
      </AppContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`<Routing />` component

```
const Routing = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      {publicRouting.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
        <Route key={i} path={path} element={component} />
      ))}
      {isAuthenticated() && (
        <Main>
          {routing.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
            <Route  key={i} path={path} element={component} />
          ))}
        </Main>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Right now console throw me this error:

```
index.tsx:19 Uncaught Error: [Routing] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

can someone tell me how to solve this problem? It looks like this component has incompatible type and cannot go as children between `Routes` component, but why they changed it? How to correct my `Routing` component?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Routes` component can have only `Route` or `React.Fragment` as a valid child, and the `Route` component can only have `Routes` or another `Route` component as parent.

The `Routes` component effectively replaced the RRDv5 `Switch` component in that it handles the route matching and rendering logic, and is now ***required*** to directly wrap the `Route` components it's managing.

Move the `Routes` component into `Routing` to wrap directly the `Route` components being mapped.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppContextProvider>
        <Routing />
      </AppContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
const Routing = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        {publicRouting.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
          <Route key={i} path={path} element={component} />
        ))}
      </Routes>
      {isAuthenticated() && (
        <Main>
          <Routes>
            {routing.map(({ path, component }, i) => (
              <Route  key={i} path={path} element={component} />
            ))}
          </Routes>
        </Main>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```